# What is the best way to copy mongo collection indexes to another collection on Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to copy indexes of one mongo collection to another collection in another database. What's the best solution on Java?

I'm using MongoTemplate to execute mongo operations. That's how I can get indexes from the original(source) collection:

```
MongoCollection<Document> srcCollection = srcMongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName);
ListIndexesIterable<Document> indexesList = srcCollection.listIndexes();
```

But how should I create the same indexes in another collection using the retrieved 'indexesList' object?

I assume I have to use something like that, but I can't understand what exactly parameters to pass into createIndexes method.

```
ListIndexesIterable<Document> indexes = srcCollection.listIndexes();
dstCollection.createIndexes(???);
```

Comment: Why Java? Do you need to do this a lot / programmatically ? If ad-hoc (or even if scripted ) out-of-the-box MongoDB tools should be able to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to implement it on Java.

Comment: I suggest you to add the code which you have tried. It will be helpful to look into it

Comment: Hi did you find an answer? I am facing this issue exactly, as I use mongock to update db I want to create a backup before hand of the collection

Comment: @RoieBeck no, I didn't. I used mongoDB shell instead

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, I created an Open Source library [`mongo-index-copy`](https://github.com/pitagoras3/mongo-index-copy). It uses `listIndexes` and `createIndexes` methods from [MongoDB Java Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/#mongodb-java-driver) to copy indexes from one collection to another. With this library you can copy all indexes from one collection to another, or you can specify names of indexes that you want to copy.

Under the hood `mongo-index-copy` firstly gets indexes definitions in `Document` objects form from source collection. Next, it maps those `Document` objects into valid `IndexModel` objects (with all possible `IndexOptions` mapped too). At the end, `mongo-index-copy` creates those indexes on destination collection using previously created `IndexModel` objects.

To use it, you can import [`mongo-index-copy`](https://github.com/pitagoras3/mongo-index-copy) using Maven / Gradle into your project, and call proper `MongoIndexCopy` method like in the example below:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
    MongoCollection<?> sourceCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("sourceCollection");
    MongoCollection<?> destinationCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("destinationCollection");
    try {
        List<String> copiedIndexes = MongoIndexCopy.copyAllIndexes(sourceCollection, destinationCollection);
        System.out.println(copiedIndexes);
    } catch (MongoIndexCopyException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Useful library, thanks for writing and sharing it!